# Missing method in assembly "System.Memory" in an UWP App

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, .net-assembly

I have a very odd issue that appeared randomly on my Universal Windows App Project.

The project compiles successfully, but I get a lot of warnings about missing methods in the assembly 'System.Memory'.

I tried to reinstall the Windows SDK and the .NET SDK, but no satisfying result was obtained.

I would be happy if anyone could have the solution, thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Care to give us a clue about one/some of the *specific* missing methods? I would guess the warning itself isn't as vague about what it's having a problem with.

Comment: Oh my apologies! I forgot to add the screenshot. Please check the attached screenshot on the original message.

Comment: Generally, warnings won't affect the app. Does your app crash when running? If it is, then that is the real problem.

Comment: Yes, the app compiles but then instantly crashes because it is using DirectoryInfo, and I have this error.

Comment: So what's the exception message or the error message? Could you please add that? I mean not the warnings, but the red error messages.

Comment: There is not any red messages. It is only Warnings. But the app still crashes at the start.

Comment: So have you tried to handle the [Application.UnhandledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-22000) to check if there are some un handled exceptions?

Comment: Still nothing...Unfortunately. I have reinstalled Windows 10 and an older version of Visual Studio, but still get the same issue.

Comment: What are the `EStorageFolder` class and the `EStorageFolder.GetFromPath` method?

Comment: It is from one library that I've made specifically for my app. It is using some Win32 functions (MoveFileFromApp, FindFirstFile, ...) to have more access to the system.
Just for your information, I have tested on a friend's PC and it works perfectly with the latest code.

Comment: That's interesting. So the code works on other devices based on your description, right?

Comment: I have not tested. I have tested only on PC and it crashes when debugging with Local Machine. (I haven't tried for Remote machine)

Comment: But you said that `I have tested on a friend's PC and it works perfectly with the latest code. `  it works on another device?

Comment: It works on every device that aren't my PC.
I have reinstalled Windows but it still doesn't start.

Comment: Does it happen to all your projects that use the same function?